# uitableview show 3 object per row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have an array with 20 objects. there can be more objects in that array. for simplicity reason lets say its only nsstring object in that array.

i want to show 3 of those elements in every row. so number of rows are

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
  int i = 0;

if ( ([myArray count] % 3) > 0 )
{
    i++;
}
return [myArray count] / 3 + i;
```

}

i have a helper veriable `int lastObj=0`

```
    - (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
  ---instaniate the cell

   for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        if (lastObj <= [myArray count])
        {
            --create cell content
            -- cellContent.myLabel.text=[myArray onbjectAtIndex:lastObj]
            --add cellContent to cell 
            lastObj++;

        }
    }
return cell;
}
```

so if i have 5 objects in that array, then they get displayed properly.
but if it the list has 14 elements then the first 9 elements gets display and it starts from element 0 and the rest dont show up. on the app you can see 3 rows and each have 3 elements of array.
so i'm trying to mimic 3 columns.

any idea how i can resolve this issue?

Comment: `NSLog` out your `lastObj` variable and see what it's getting set to each loop.

Comment: it does not go over 12 it always gets plus 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
      ---instaniate the cell
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init]; //If you don't ARC then retain accordingly. 

    }

       for (int i = indexPath.row * 3 ; i < indexPath.row * 3 + 3; i++)
        {


            if (i <= [myArray count])
            {

                --create cell content
                -- cellContent.myLabel.text=[myArray onbjectAtIndex:i]
                --add cellContent to cell 
                //forget about your last object helper. That would not work anyway. 

            }
        }
    return cell;
}
```

The Point is that cellForRowAtIndexPath is not nessessarily called in a certain sequence. It is rather coincidence that it is called for the first to seventh row from start. Theoretically it could be called in any sequence. 
Think of this: 
Your table has 30 rows. 10 of thes are visible at once. 
At the beginning it is called for row 0 to 9. But understand that as a coincidence. It could be called in any sequence. 
Then the user scrolls for 5 rows. The method is then called for cell 10 to 14. In this case the cells will be re-used. Your `if (cell==nil)` branch will not be entered. 
 Again in a row. Then the user crolls back 2 rows. Next calls of the method would be for row 9 and 8 - in that sequence.

So do never ever assume a certain sequence here, even if you seem to observe a certain sequence.

Comment: your code acutually displays and in first row: obj0 obj1 obj2
second row: obj1 obj2 obj3. thanks but that look funny

Comment: It is rather important that you get the message about the sequence of cellForRowAtIndexPath beeing called, about the concept of reusing cells and that you have to (re-)set the data for each cell every time the method is used, regardless whether cell is nil at that point or not.

Comment: if the for loop is outside if statement then you can see content on top of eachother. otherwise your solution is third one which shows the first 12 objects then starts with first object

Comment: The loop - or whatever you use to set the content of the cell - has to be outside of the if statement. If there is something on top of something else then fix the related layout issue rather then questioning whether the loop should be outside the if or not. Key is that - if 10 cells are displayed - the 1st cell will be reused to display the 11th row. In that case cell ist not nil (because dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier does return a cell) but you will have to assign the data/content of the 11th row anyway.

Comment: oh ok thanks for the clarification. now i got it worked. i went with your solution cause it was close to mine. thanks! since i was adding views to cell.contentview i had to remove views. i dont know if its good idea adding views and then remove in terms of performance on the device.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
   return ceil(((float)[myArray count]) / 3.0);
  }

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
  ---instaniate the cell
}
   //initiate 3 labels, then say:

   if(myArray.count-1 >= IndexPath.row * 3)
       cellContent.myLabel_1.text=[myArray onbjectAtIndex:IndexPath.row * 3];

   if(myArray.count-1 >= (IndexPath.row * 3)+1)
       cellContent.myLabel_2.text=[myArray onbjectAtIndex:(IndexPath.row * 3)+1];

   if(myArray.count-1 >= (IndexPath.row * 3)+2)
       cellContent.myLabel_3.text=[myArray onbjectAtIndex:(IndexPath.row * 3)+2];

   //the above "if"-s are to prevent reading values out of the array's bounds
   //add labels to cell 

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to understand your solution. why are we doing times 3 (IndexPath.row * 3)?

Comment: you have 20 objects, 20/3=6(+2), so you need 6+1=7 rows in your table.

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath will get called 7 times. each time you need to read 3 values from your array

Comment: indexPath.row tells you which time is the methot getting called. This is why you must multiply indexPath.row with 3, as you need 3 objects from array. for each row, you read the value from array 3 times: row +0, row+1 and row+2 are the indexes from array

Comment: i still dont get it( need some coffee) what if i have 3000 obejcts?

Comment: ok i just tried your solution the first 12 elements get display then starts with 1st element

Comment: your solution shows the same result i had before but less code :-P

Comment: Dude, you said you wanna "mimic 3 colums"? Just implement 3 sections and you are done

Comment: yes mimic 3 columns. i have one array. so getting 3 objects at once for each row is the problem. after 12 objects it starts with the first object

Comment: Dude, you are doing something wrong beyond the curtains, I cannot help you. help yourself.

Comment: your solution works if i dont use [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]. but think it should be used, right?

Comment: If I have 7 items, only 6 gets displayed. 7th one isn't. :|

Answer (score 0):

There is currently only 1 text label in the cell you are trying to insert 3 text labels in. You seem to be close but I think the best option is to create a custom table cell with three text labels and then set them as you are currently doing here is a tutorial to setup custom tabel cells: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/